# scala singletons in spark - runtime to infinity

Tags: scala, apache-spark, singleton

I'm trying to reduce my memory use in a spark app, so I thought maybe using singleton objects for data that was massively repeated would help.

It compiled fine, didn't throw any runtime errors...  CPU usage in Ganglia was pinned...  but nothing ever happened.  Memory usage never even ramped up, and the first thing it does is read in some JSON.  A ten minute test run just churned for hours and nothing happened.

This toy example shows the gist of what I was trying to do.  The singleton objects in `A`'s companion object were the problem.  As soon as I got rid of them and just let it create a zillion instances of identical data, it ran fine again.

```
case class A(u: U) { val isDefined: Boolean = true }

object A {
  object NULL extends A(???) { override val isDefined = false }
  object A1 extends A(???)

  def apply(u: U): A = 
    if (???) NULL 
    else if (???) A1
    else A(u)
}


def toA[T : Manifest](rw: Row): Try[A] = Try {
  // Row => String
  val json: String = rw.getAs[String](0)

  // parse JSON
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  val jval: JValue = parse(json)
  val t: T = jval.extract[T]

  // to final class
  t match {
    case ??? => A(t)
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
  }
}

val rdd: RDD[Row] = ???
val rdd2: RDD[A] = rdd.map(toA)
```

Why did the singletons bog everything down?  Is there a way to get them to work?  Was this a bad idea in the first place?

Comment: you should get stacktraces of what is actually happening, the obvious conclusion is a deadlock but only stacks/profiling/threaddump etc. would clearly show this and hint as to where the deadlock is (or prove it isn't one).